# Tensorflow Installing gives me an error from pip module

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

So, as the title says, I get an error whenever I try to install TensorFlow like this:

> pip install tensorflow

Here is the error that I get:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   
> File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main "__main__", mod_spec) 
> File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)   
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I have read a lot of solutions here on Stack but none of them was succesfull for me. Some of them said to set environment variables which I already had but I tried to set them again, still same thing. 
Does anyone have a solid solution ?

Comment: Did you try the way it is described in [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)?

Comment: @luigigi I hope that's a joke, man. That was what I have tried first. I even get an error when I try this: pip3 --version. I assume that my pip has some problems but I can't solve them

Comment: What are your system specs.  E.g. linux, mac, windows?  version?  Disk space?  How far along in the installation process do you get?  Give us all the gory details.

Comment: @mathewgunther ok. So, I'm using Windows 10. I do have 17gb left on my ssd. Basically I got this as soon as it starts..

Comment: @Adrian Since your description is very short and unhelpful, I think the tip is quite justified.

Comment: I'm not a windows, user, so I don't have much help to give.  However, I believe the latest anaconda comes with tensorflow, and I've installed anaconda without problems on windows machines in the past.   See download link here for anaconda

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

That said, tensorflow recently updated to version 2.0 and I'm not sure if anaconda is up to date with that.

Comment: @Adrian Can you install other packages? I ask because since it happens right at the beginning without reaching tensorflow packages, it might be a problem with your pip/python installation.

Comment: @Adrian Also, I think that tensorflow only support 64bits. You might need to install Python-3.6-64bit instead.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé no, I can't install any packages using cmd. But I can install some using Install Libraries from PyCharm

Comment: @Adrian Try uninstalling python 32 bits and reinstall python 64bits.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using conda try `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`, I heard that Tensorflow is not great on Windows so if you're installing it just to use Keras I would suggest to install Theano instead.